# How to get java to use provided path as literal path

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, azure-synapse

I'm running a Scala app on a synapse spark cluster.  I've mounted a file at:

`synfs:/myPath/myFile.txt`

If I try:

`val file = Paths.get("synfs:/myPath/myFile.txt").toFile()`

It tries to find the file at `javaTmpDir/synfs:/myPath/myFile.txt`, which doesn't exist

If I switch to:

`synfs://myPath/myFile.txt`

Then at least it uses it as an absolute path and tries to find the file at `synfs://myPath/myFile.txt`, but that doesn't exist either because the mount is at one forward slash, not two forward slashes.

And if I switch to:

`/synfs:/myPath/myFile.txt`

Well that also works in taking it as an absolute path, but the file doesn't really exist there either.

I also tried playing around with methods like `getAbsolutePath()` but that doesn't work either.

So how can I say:

`val file = Paths.get("synfs:/myPath/myFile.txt").toFile()`

And force java to take that as the literal path I really want to use?

Or maybe there is some other special trick to getting java to read from a mounted directory?  Here is the mount if it helps:

```
mssparkutils.fs.mount( 
    "abfss://mycontainer@txdb.dfs.core.windows.net/mypath/", 
    "/mnt", 
    Map("linkedService" -> "mylinkedservice")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is applicable to all situations, but for mine specifically, I was finally able to get it to take a literal path in this format.

`val file = Paths.get("/synfs/myPath/myFile.txt").toFile()`

Note the absence of the colon.